# Перенос Объекта в Сессии

Tags: php, ооп, сессия, объекты

Ребята возник такой вопрос: Как перенести объект ( без методов ) по сессии? 
К примеру такой код:

```
$_SESSION["ErrorsRegistration"]= new Err("Не работает");
```

А потом на другой страничке как нужно вытащить Err->message?

Comment: сариализуйте объект, например, или представьте это дело в виде массива.

Comment: [читать документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.serialization.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.serialization.php)

> Функция `serialize()` возвращает строковое представление любого
>   значения, которое может быть сохранено в PHP. Функция `unserialize()`
>   использует эту строку для восcтановления исходного значения
>   переменной. Использование `serialize` для сериализации объекта сохранит
>   имя класса и все его свойства, однако методы не сохраняются.

поэтому на первой странице вы делаете:

```
$err = new Err("Не работает");
$_SESSION["ErrorsRegistration"] = serialize($err);
```

на второй странице

```
$err = unserialize($_SESSION["ErrorsRegistration"] );
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую, Надеюсь сработает

Comment: И вопрос если у меня массив Объектов я могу serialize(массив) ?

Comment: можете "_serialize() обрабатывает все типы, кроме resource. Возможно также сериализовать массивы, которые содержат ссылки на себя_" (с) [документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php)